# Python: Functions where a variable with the same name of the input is generated

Tags: python, function

Apologies for any possible confusion about the title. I will try my best to illustrate my question.

Context:

I just finished working on an interesting coding problem on [CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/directions-reduction/python) where I was asked to write a function to simplify a list of directions.

The input will look like `["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]`

The `'SOUTH' 'NORTH'` and `'EAST' 'WEST'` that are next to each other shall both be deleted since it makes little sense to go north and then immediately south. And the list shall be simplified until it can't be simplified anymore.

For instance:

```
["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
```

shall be simplified to

```
['WEST']
```

Dummy OP wrote a clunky function that does it. But my question is about a really clever answer posted by someone else.

Code:

```
def dirReduc(arr):
    dir = " ".join(arr)
    dir2 = dir.replace("NORTH SOUTH",'').replace("SOUTH NORTH",'').replace("EAST WEST",'').replace("WEST EAST",'')
    dir3 = dir2.split()
    return dirReduc(dir3) if len(dir3) < len(arr) else dir3
```

I played with it and see that it works but just couldn't wrap my head around how.

I see that in the return statement, it shall run again unless the result has the same length as input, which is understandable. But the code uses `dirReduc(dir3)` which seems wrong to me.

If I run `dirReduc(dir3)` then my input will be `dir3`, but then inside the frame of the function, another `dir3` is created. So now when the function goes to the final return statement it shall be `return dirReduc(dir3) if len(dir3) < len(dir3) else dir3`. And since `len(dir3) == len(dir3)', it will just return`dir3`.

In my understanding, the function will be run twice, max with each input, which is not the truth. So which part of my understanding is wrong?

Sorry for the sheer volume of words, I think after all this is a simple problem. There must be a very fundamental thing that I'm getting wrong.

Comment: `dir3` are *local* variables to each function execution, they are unrelated to each other.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the quick response. Would you care to elaborate a little bit please. The `dir3` generated inside the function is local variable? Which is unrelated to which? And when the return statement evaluates `len(dir3)`, hasn't it been changed to the local variable already?

Comment: this solution fails for `['NORTH', 'WEST', 'SOUTH']`

Comment: @kyrill because they will only be deleted if they are RIGHT NEXT to each other. Sorry for not making it clear enough.

Comment: krill's solution could be reduced to `["WEST"]; adjacent pairs are just a special case of opposite directions on opposite ends of a sequence.

Comment: @chepner OP is right -- according to the description on the linked site, the path `['NORTH', 'WEST', 'SOUTH']` is not reducible. i haven't read the description at first, so i thought it was. but it isn't

Comment: That's boring :)

Answer (score 3):

Local variables in different stack frames are completely unrelated to each other, even if they share the same name. Each recursive call creates a new stack frame, so `dir3` in one call is completely different from `dir3` in another.

Imagine you had a non-recursive function that only reduced the path by one step:

```
def dirReducOneStep(arr):
    dir = " ".join(arr)
    dir2 = dir.replace("NORTH SOUTH",'').replace("SOUTH NORTH",'').replace("EAST WEST",'').replace("WEST EAST",'')
    dir3 = dir2.split()
    return dir3

print(dirReducOneStep(dirReducOneStep(dirReducOneStep(path))))
```

The only difference is that `dirReduc` calls itself on a reduced path, rather than forcing the caller to decide whether or not to call it again on the previous output.

Comment: I would argue that the second problem is in fact less interesting. Its optimal solution runs in _Ө(n)_ time and _Ө(log n)_ auxiliary space. However, the given solution to the original problem requires _Ο(n^2)_ time, albeit only _Ө(1)_ space (assuming tail-call optimization, which à propos is not the case with Python, so it's in fact _Ο(n)_ space). An alternative solution would require _Ө(n)_ time and _Ο(n)_ space (to maintain a stack of counters, one for each N/S or E/W level).

Comment: Yes, but why would you only want a partially compressed path, instead of the shortest possible path? That's what I meant by "more interesting".

Comment: Imagine you are at coordinate (0,0). You need to go 2 units to the east -- to (0,2), but there is an obstacle at (0,1). So you cannot just "compress" N-E-E-S to E-E because you would run into the obstacle. Imagine the input directions describe a walk in a directed graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#walk); what you want to do is make it into a simple path (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_path).

Comment: Ok, that's a good point. I was thinking of a fully connected space.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the basic concept of stack frame. Please lemme know if I'm understanding correctly. After the first iteration, when the function is going to run `dirReduc(dir3)`, this `dir3` is established in the first stack frame, and in the run of `dirReduc(dir3)`, the return statement will be `dirReduc(dir3(2nd stack frame) if len(dir3(2nd stack frame)) < len(dir3(first stack frame)`. Did I get it right? Thanks again.

Comment: Kind of, if you think of `dir3` as a function that takes a stack frame as an argument and returns the value of the variable `dir3` in that stack frame. Think of a stack frame as a set of local variables, and all lookups occur in the stack frame associated with a particular call to the function.

Comment: @BowenLiu Yes, that is correct. @chepner I suppose he didn't mean the parentheses to represent a function call but rather a description of which `dir3` it is. [As a side note, the assumption in my first comment that the original implementation runs in _Ο(n)_ space (without tail-call optimization) is incorrect. It's actually _Ο(n^2)_ space. But that's just a detail.]

Comment: @kyrill You are absolutely right that I tried to use the () for description purpose. I just don't know if there is a conventional way to do it. And what do you mean by Ο(n) space? Is it referring to the steps it takes to get the result?

Comment: No, it's referring to the space it takes on the stack. It takes space proportional to the square of the length of the input sequence. The length of the input sequence is _n_, and the space it takes to compute the result is at most _c * n^2_ where _c_ is some positive constant. This is conventionally noted as _Ο(n)_. See more **here**: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/ or **here**: https://medium.com/karuna-sehgal/a-simplified-explanation-of-the-big-o-notation-82523585e835

Comment: To expand, _n_ is the number of directions, and in the **worst case**, it takes asymptotically _c * n^2_ time (number of steps) as well as space (data on the stack). This is because the worst case looks something like this: NNNNNNSSSSSS. The algorithm would remove NS from the middle and then do a recursive call; while keeping its own original input on the stack. The new invocation of `reducDirs` would now occupy _n - 2_ bytes on the stack (since we removed 2 characters from `arr`). Then would remove another 2 characters and do another recursive invocation.

Comment: This means that at the "bottom", when we are in the last invocation, there would be _n + n-2 + n-4 ... + 2_ bytes on the stack. That is equal to _(n/2) * (n/2+1)_, or _n*(n+2) / 4_. If we leave out the division by 4 (because we can set _c = 1/4_), we get _n^2 + 2n_. And since _lim(x->inf) x^2 + x  =  lim(x->inf) x^2_, we can leave out the _2n_ and we get just _n^2_. We can do this since we care about **asymptotic** complexity, eg. when input size tends to infinity. See formal notations on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Answer (score 1):

It is a basic concept. Every function has its own stack, or let's say scope.

You can image that a function is a box. Local variables are inside the box. So if there are many functions, then there are many boxes. Every box has its own local variables. That's like:

```
BoxA
--variable_a
BoxB
--varibale_a
```

Although these two variables have the same name, they are in different boxes. So they are different varibales at all.

Further, BoxA(Actually functionA) cannot access the variable_a in BoxB, it is outside of its scope, so it is safe even these two variables have the same name.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks a lot. I didn't think the concept of stack frame is important when I learned it. Now I know.